# React JS - Error Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was testing out `useSyncExternalStore` to replace a store subscription used with `useEffect`,

Basically this is the usage of the hook,

```
 const state = BoardState.getInstance();

 const boardUIstate = useSyncExternalStore(
   (observer) => state.subscribe(observer),
   () => getUiStateFromExternalState(state.getState())
 );
```

The `state` is a class implemented with classic observable pattern combine with a singleton,

```
export class BoardState<T> extends Subject<T> {
  private static instance: BoardState<unknown> | undefined;

  private constructor() {
    super();
  }

  public static getInstance<T>(): BoardState<T> {
    if (!BoardState.instance) {
      BoardState.instance = new BoardState();
      return BoardState.instance as BoardState<T>;
    }
    return BoardState.instance as BoardState<T>;
  }
}
```

The extended `Subject` class tracks the state and the observers & implements the subscribe - unsubscribe methods,

```
export class Subject<T> {
  protected state: T | undefined;
  private observers: any[] = [];

  subscribe(fn: (newState: T | undefined) => void) {
    this.observers.push(fn);
    return () => this.unsubscribe(fn);
  }

  private unsubscribe(fn: (newState: T | undefined) => void) {
    this.observers = this.observers.filter((ob) => ob !== fn);
  }

  setState(state: T) {
    this.state = state;
    this.observers.map((ob) => ob(this.state));
  }

  ...
}
```

I can see on my local development server, it is complaining about this,

> Warning: The result of getSnapshot should be cached to avoid an
> infinite loop

What's this caching ? How do I do that ? ( [bug](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24508) ? )

With the error,

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
> repeatedly calls setState  inside componentWillUpdate or
> componentDidUpdate.  React limits the number of nested updates to
> prevent infinite loops.

Above external state works with `useEffect` & i can not see any issue with the implementation either. Any thoughts ?

---

Sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-carson-frs92s?file=/src/index.tsx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Bad, [Found out](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/86) that I need to use `use-sync-external-store/with-selector`

So I changed my code from,

```
 const state = BoardState.getInstance();

 const boardUIstate = useSyncExternalStore(
   (observer) => state.subscribe(observer),
   () => getUiStateFromExternalState(state.getState())
 );
```

to

```
import {useSyncExternalStoreWithSelector} from 'use-sync-external-store/with-selector';

const state = BoardState.getInstance();

const boardUIstate = useSyncExternalStoreWithSelector<
  Record<string, string | null> | undefined,
  (number | null)[]
>(
  state.subscribe.bind(state),
  () => {
     const state = state.getState();
     return state;
  },
  undefined,
  (snapshot) => {
     return getUiStateFromExternalState(snapshot)
   }
);
```